# How to delete a project - Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am using VS 2015 and Visual Studio Team Services. I have created several projects and now I would like to delete some of them. I can not find the option to delete a project. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are trying to delete a team project you can do so from the admin section reachable by clicking the gear icon in the upper-right corner of the you.

You will access the Admin section where you'll see the list of team projects. By clicking on the `...` icon near the project you want to delete you''l open a dropdown with a Delete option.

For further info and a step to step guide you can refer to the [official documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/delete-team-project)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Do you know how to remove deleted projects from the recent projects list? (drop down from the main menu)

Comment: In the homepage dashboard you should see a "Recent projects & teams" section. Hovering a project will show an x button to remove it from that list

Comment: In the current version of team services, use the gear icon to access the Overview section, where you can delete the project.

Comment: As of Dec 2018, the drop down menu that includes delete is opened by clicking on the dot dot dot next to the project in the projects list.

Answer (score 23):

With the latest changes done on the UI of VSTS you can navigate to [https://{yourtenant}.visualstudio.com/_admin](https://%7Byourtenant%7D.visualstudio.com/_admin) then in the **Overview** tab you will see a list of all the projects, select the one you want to delete from there.

[image]

Comment: click on the "..." in the listing to see the drop down that includes "delete"

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to your Visual Studio Team Services Accounts like name.visualstudio.com
2. Click the Gear Icon and then Overview
3. Select your project, **right** click and Delete.

   [image: Step 1]
   [image: Step 2]
   [image: Step 3]

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can delete your project in Team Foundation Server 2017 Version.

First, navigate to your Project first. Then choose the gear icon, and select Collection Settings:

[image]

Afterwards, select the project you want to delete, there is a **three dot** option that you can click to show the delete option, then select it.

[image]